# What does "that was his last blow at fate" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> He thought Almighty God had dealt cruelly and unjustly with him; and felt, somehow, that he was paying Him back in kind when he stabbed thus into his wife's soul. Moreover he no longer loved her, because of the unconscious injury she had brought upon his home and his name.
>
> She turned away like one stunned by a blow, and walked slowly towards the door, hoping he would call her back.
>
> "Good-by, Armand," she moaned.
>
> He did not answer her. **That was his last blow at fate.**

Dose it mean that it was his last chance  to return to his wife and he did not care about it?

This context is from the story named "Désirée 's Baby" by Kate Chopin

Answer (score 1):

In this passage "fate" is equivalent to "God".  By treating his wife cruelly, the subject believes he is somehow striking back at God's unfairness.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Concerning your answer , does it mean that he takes his last revenge from god ?and does "blow" means "revenge".? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ViserHashemi  That's what the story says.  You'll have to read on to see if it's really his "last".  As for "blow" it usually refers to some kind of physical attack, so in this case it's used metaphorically.  See https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blow  **noun (3)**